# Temp arrays not working after adding 3rd Item

Tags: java, arrays

I had to make a `Temp array` to keep resizing the array list if the user decides to keep adding items to the cart, but my `Temp array` works until I try to add 3 different items to the cart.

I was instructed to do it this way instead of an `array list` to show the difficulty of arrays.

```
     orderProduct [productCount] = aProduct;
     orderQuantity [productCount] = aQuantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to increase `productCount` when there is already a product in the cart.

Moreover, you can just set the product and quantity array to the temp arrays instead of copying back.

```
orderProduct = tempOrderedProducts;
orderQuantity = tempOrderedQuantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot `productCount++` after resizing the array.
The following code will work:

```
public void setOrderProduct(Product aProduct, int aQuantity) {

    if (productCount == 0) {
        orderProduct[0] = aProduct;
        orderQuantity[0] = aQuantity;

    } else {
        Product[] tempOrderedProducts = new Product[orderProduct.length + 1];
        int[] tempOrderedQuantity = new int[orderQuantity.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < orderProduct.length; i++) {
            tempOrderedProducts[i] = orderProduct[i];
            tempOrderedQuantity[i] = orderQuantity[i];
        }
        orderProduct = new Product[tempOrderedProducts.length];
        orderQuantity = new int[tempOrderedQuantity.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < orderQuantity.length; i++) {
            orderProduct[i] = tempOrderedProducts[i];
            orderQuantity[i] = tempOrderedQuantity[i];
        }
        orderProduct[productCount] = aProduct;
        orderQuantity[productCount] = aQuantity;

        productCount++; //you forgot this
    }
}
```

What's more, there is a simple way to deal with array copy:

```
public void setOrderProduct(Product aProduct, int aQuantity) {

    if (productCount == 0) {
        orderProduct[0] = aProduct;
        orderQuantity[0] = aQuantity;

    } else {

        Product[] tempOrderedProducts = new Product[orderProduct.length + 1];
        int[] tempOrderedQuantity = new int[orderQuantity.length + 1];

        //System.arraycopy is more convenient and efficient
        System.arraycopy(orderProduct, 0, tempOrderedProducts, 0, orderProduct.length);
        System.arraycopy(orderQuantity, 0, tempOrderedQuantity, 0, orderQuantity.length);

        //you don't need to copy back, just re-assign the reference 
        orderProduct = tempOrderedProducts;
        orderQuantity = tempOrderedQuantity;

        orderProduct[productCount] = aProduct;
        orderQuantity[productCount] = aQuantity;

        productCount++;
    }
}
```